# How to send synchronous request from d3.js

Tags: d3.js

Actually I am facing with a problem. d3.json, d3.csv all of them send asynchronous request. So I am facing problem with a case in my visualization. I need to send synchronous request using d3.js so that it waits till data is loaded and can be used by following few lines of codes. If i can't do that following few lines are going to get null pointer exception. Do you have any idea how can i do this using d3.js? In ajax from jquery probably it was enough to keep a callback function. How can i do this in d3.js?

Comment: You can also use jQuery within D3.js and do a callback

Comment: Any idea how can i do that so that following few lines of code after d3.csv(); doesn't get executed till data loading is done?

Comment: See the second answer and see how the function is being called http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15261313/how-do-i-load-json-data-synchronously-with-d3-js

Comment: Thanks. I got an idea. Let me have a try